# boot failure when trying to run Ubuntu from USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I've been trying to use ubuntu on an older laptop, but can't.

I created a bootable disk on my desktop computer which is running win 10, using Rufus and the latest version of Ubuntu. I changed the boot sequence on my computer to USB, when I start the computer I get a boot failure, remove disk and try again message. I've tried to create a bootable USB from that laptop and I get an error while Rufus is extracting the ISO.

I can run Cub Linux on this computer from a USB created in the same way using Rufus, but not Ubuntu, its a Toshiba running win 7 pro, can anyone give me any assistance and/or solutions ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: My friend, could you please post logs, & screenshots of the error messages?

Comment: Also, do not be afraid to keep us updated on your situation =]

Comment: Please specify the computer hardware with more details:  - Brand name and model 
- CPU 
- RAM (size) 
- graphics chip/card 
- wifi chip/card. 
It will make it easier to give specific advice.